# Hard disk locked

Tags: mount, virtual-console, unlock

I have a problem, mi external hard disk is locked. Someone knows how to solve this problem. When I try to access it by inserting the password, an error message appears. It says: 'Error unlocking, failed to activate device. Operation not permitted'.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: is it encrypted? have you tried mounting as root from command line? 'sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt` ?

Comment: Was this drive used by Windows the last time?